# Не работает Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
import sys

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys



browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('https://vk.com')

textarea = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#index_email')

textarea.send_keys('')

textarea = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#index_pass')

textarea.send_keys('')

submit = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#index_login_button')

submit.click()


# DEBUG
def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    import traceback
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    sys.exit(1)

sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions
```

Пишет вот такие ошибки

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/Tom/Desktop/spammer/spammer.py", line 10, in <module>
>     browser = webdriver.Firefox()
>   File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\
>       selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 167, in __init__
>     keep_alive=True)
>   File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\
>       selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 156, in __init__
>     self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
>   File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\s
>       elenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 251, in start_session
>     response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
>   File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\
>       selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
>     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>   File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\
>       selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
>     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find 
>     a matching set of capabilities
> ```

Comment: пароль сменил, можете не пробовать кто увидел XD

Comment: У вас установлен geckodriver?
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Comment: @nick_gabpe Да, Геко драйвер закинул в папку с запускаемым файлом

Comment: пропишите ещё на всякий случай executable_path='/path/to/geckodriver',  firefox_binary='/path/to/firefox/binary'

Comment: @nick_gabpe где прописать? Извиняюсь за тупость

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробовать, чтобы убедиться на 100% что это не вина geckodriver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
binary = FirefoxBinary(path_to_ff_exe)
profile = FirefoxProfile(path_to_ff_profile) # если запускаетесь с дефолтным, то можно пропустить
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_binary=binary, executable_path=path_to_geckodriver)
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Tom/Desktop/spammer/spammer.py", line 10, in <module>
    binary = FirefoxBinary(path_to_ff_exe)
NameError: name 'FirefoxBinary' is not defined`

Comment: @МаксимХалин обновил ответ

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Tom/Desktop/spammer/spammer.py", line 11, in <module>
    binary = FirefoxBinary(path_to_ff_exe)
NameError: name 'path_to_ff_exe' is not defined`

Comment: path_to_ff_exe нужно заменить на путь до исполняемого файла Firefox, а path_to_geckodriver на путь до geckodrivera

Comment: pycharm подчёркивает мне \Users

Comment: Попробуйте "C:\\Users\\Tom/Desktop\\spammer\\spammer.py"

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, помогли. Отметил как ответ + реп кинул

Comment: Опять проблемка, не поможете? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/920076/selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-message-unable-to-find-a